# Yii2 bad response format for JSON

Tags: php, json, yii2, encode, x-editable

Code:

```
public function actionTest()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
    return ['test' => 1];
}
```

Response:

```
<?php{"test":1}
```

I don't understand why <\?php" is appending to the response. I try to use:

```
Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
```

and

```
return Json::encode(['test' => 1]);
```

but it did not help for me

Comment: Hmm there is nothing wrong with your actionTest() method. Could there be something wrong in your server settings, or something funky happening when yii is bootstrapped?

Comment: Does the class that has that action in it (i.e. the controller) `use` the `yii\web\Response`? I.e. have you tested that that constant is working? Side note: unless that's the only action you're looking to echo JSON out of, it might be best to set this configuration value within the application configuration directly

Comment: I found solution: Yii2 created boostrap.php file in backend with content "<?php". Everytime request goes throught boostrap.php it appends boostrap.php content and echoes JSON. Thanks for replies :)

Answer (score 0):

You should `echo` the result. Here is the correct function:

```
public function actionTest()
{
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;//optional
    echo Json::encode(['test' => 1]);
    return;
}
```